# How can I install Miktex on Jammy Jellyfish?

Tags: latex

In the MikTex website, they only give download information for ubuntu Focal Fossa. Using apt does not work either (uninstallable dependencies)

Comment: I don't know about MikTeX, but you can install full latex 2021 with `sudo apt install texlive-full`.

Comment: They haven't released any information yet for 22.04 .  If their instructions for an older distribution of Ubuntu doesn't work for you, you'll need to ask them.  It isn't part of standard Ubuntu; if it was, their standard [instructions](https://miktex.org/download) wouldn't ask you to add them to `sources.list`.

Answer (score 4):

The following worked for me

1. Register GPG key

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys D6BC243565B2087BC3F897C9277A7293F59E4889
```

2. Register the installation source

```
echo "deb http://miktex.org/download/ubuntu jammy universe" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/miktex.list
```

3. Install Miktex

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install miktex
```

4. Finish the setup

```
sudo miktexsetup --shared=yes finish
```

5. Here miktex was giving me some trouble because of the bin path, so run the following to fix it.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/<usr>/bin
or 
export PATH=$PATH:<path-to-your-bin>
```