# Broken Packages Held when installing Miktex

Tags: package-management, latex

I was trying to install latex on Ubuntu 22.04 by installing miktex. After following the steps outlined on the website, I ran into the following error message:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 miktex : Depends: libboost-locale1.65.1 but it is not installable
          Depends: libhunspell-1.6-0 but it is not installable
          Depends: libicu60 (>= 60.1-1~) but it is not installable
          Depends: liblog4cxx10v5 (>= 0.10.0) but it is not installable
          Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I googled around, and tried to install openssl 1.1.1 manually. However, the error messages seem to persist. Any suggestions as to what I should undertake to fix this?

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep hold
```

yields no output

and

```
sudo aptitude install miktex
```

yields

```
sudo aptitude install miktex       
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libqt5concurrent5{a} libqt5qml5{a} libqt5script5{a} libqt5scripttools5{a} libqt5xml5{a} 
  liburiparser1{a} libzzip-0-13{a} miktex{b} 
0 packages upgraded, 8 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 38.0 MB of archives. After unpacking 121 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 miktex : Depends: libboost-locale1.65.1 which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package

          Depends: libhunspell-1.6-0 which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package

          Depends: libicu60 (>= 60.1-1~) which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package

          Depends: liblog4cxx10v5 (>= 0.10.0) which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package

          Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0) which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package
```

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10 is out of support, and you will encounter errors while installing packages on it. Please perform fresh install of Ubuntu 22.10 LTS (supported until 2027), and ask a new question if you still encounter any errors in it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: I'm sorry, that was a typo on my part. I upgraded to 22.10 from 22.04 last week, so I do have the latest version of Ubuntu installed.

Comment: @Nmath I read through the post and tried both solutions and shared the output in the post. Trying to get a list of those broken packages returns nothing, and an aptitude install doesn't seem to find the 'miketex' package.

Comment: What ppa are you installing 'miktex' from? It looks like you are using something that is designed for an earlier version of Ubuntu. Definitely if you are following this: https://miktex.org/howto/install-miktex-unx

Comment: Also you keep typing `miketex` (for example, in the 2nd screenshot) and it's `miktex`.

Comment: @Organic Marble Corrected the typo, however, I roughly get the same error as before. I also tried following the instructions here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1414141/how-can-i-install-miktex-on-jammy-jellyfish, which is the closest I seem to get to 22.10 I still doesn't work, tells me that I'm holding broken packages. Some of them are actually installed, so I'm not sure why it's not detecting them.

Comment: I changed my questions based on your remarks. I followed the instructions on the miktex website. I think I originally used those for Ubuntu 20.04, but they also have a set for 22.04. This only yields two broken package errors. However, I don't get what I could do. It's basically asking me for libicu70 or higher, and I have libicu-dev 71.1-3ubuntu1 installed. Same case for the other broken package (liblog4cxx12).
I'll look for something else to install latex, do you have any good suggestions?

Comment: I followed the instructions here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1414141/how-can-i-install-miktex-on-jammy-jellyfish in a fresh 22.04 virtual machine and they worked without error. The packages that yours are complaining about, e.g. `libicu60` were not used (do not even exist on my system), so I am not sure at all what you are doing. Perhaps it would be good to add the exact commands -all of them - you typed in to your question.

Comment: I basically followed the instructions on the website:
```sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys D6BC243565B2087BC3F897C9277A7293F59E4889```

then

```echo "deb http://miktex.org/download/ubuntu jammy universe" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/miktex.list```

finally

```sudo apt-get update```

```sudo apt-get install miktex```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I install Miktex on Jammy Jellyfish?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1414141/how-can-i-install-miktex-on-jammy-jellyfish)

Comment: Unfortunately not. I guess it's just due to MikTex not updating the installation for 22.10 I installed LaTeX another way now. But thank you for all the help.